# Calling shell script as another user from PHP in specific directory

Tags: php, linux, shell

I'm writing a PHP front-end that uses some shell scripts. However, the problem is I have to call the script in a very specific directory (accessible but not owned by www-data) as a specific user.

```
$command = './myscript.py 2>&1 |  tee /tmp/outputfile.txt';       // set the command
$cwd = 'cd /home/secondUser/myscript';                                // set current working directory
$wrapper = 'echo "Password" | sudo -u secondUser bash -c';        // add extra wrappers
$fullCommand = $cwd.';'.$wrapper.' "'.$command.'"';             // combine subcommands
$output = system($fullCommand);
```

I was trying different execute command (shell_exec, exec...). However, all the time I find following error in logs:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

The problem is not only to run the shell script (e.g. by editing sudoers), but to run it as a specific ruser.

Any tips or tricks to do so?

Comment: Why don't you just drop the information into a specific directory and collect it via a Cron Job and execute from the cron your specific script with the information? Imagine somebody can directly sudo into your machine from a website, doesn't sound safe to me...

Answer (score 0):

1) ## Heading ##This is not PHP related, but unix related, so it should probably be moved to some other stackexchange server.

Also the log line you are mentioning is telling you exactly what the problem is. Sudo will not allow you to pass it a password from a script, it requires a terminal (tty) so that it can turn off local echo (so you don't the the letters you type as a password). You can override it in sudoers file. But you should probably solve it completely differently, either by using private password-less keys to login as different user using SSH, or by allowing to "sudo" a command without password. Both are mentioned here:

2) They already solved this problem at:
https://serverfault.com/questions/160524/using-su-inside-of-a-shell-script

Comment: Thank you for your tips, however it didn't work. I'm receiving the same error plus help for sudo is returned.